# Android Get the data from User And pass the data to multiple activities

Tags: android, bundle

I have android app for login, when user gives login details that data have to pass in multiple activities.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    passwrd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Pass_word);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = username.getText().toString();
            String password = passwrd.getText().toString();
            new Mytask().execute(email, password);
        }
    });

}
```

I want to pass email and password to multiple activities..

I just tried Bundle.
                                                               I stored email value as "name".
And i just passed the value to another activity(Below code).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testpage);

    Entertext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tex_id);
    Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_mit);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Text = Entertext.getText().toString();
            Intent i = getIntent();
            Bundle b = i.getBundleExtra("personBdl");
            String name = b.getString("name");

            new Mytask().execute(name,Text);
        }
    });

private class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder dta = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://xxxyyy.com/insert.php?user=" + params[0] + "&value=" + params[1]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                InputStream it = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(it);
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
                dta = new StringBuilder();
                String chunks;
                while ((chunks = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                    dta.append(chunks);
                }
            } else {
                //Handle else
            }
            return dta.toString();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Email has passed as "name"(bundle).
"name" value passed as params[0] to my php file.
But params[0] not passed to my php file.

Could you please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use SharedPreferences instead of Bundle.

Save data like this:

```
SharedPreferences sPref;
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString("email", etText.getText().toString());
    ed.putString("password", etText.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
```

And get it in your activities like this:

```
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sPref.getString("email", "");
    String password = sPref.getString("password", "");
    etText.setText(savedText);
```

And I also recommend you to use it in separate thread.

Comment: I tried this but how can i pass these value to url. 
After i refered shared prefreance "email" have to pass as "user". In url


 URL url = new URL("http://xxxyyy.com/insert.php?user=" + params[0] + "&value=" + params[1]);


Could you please Tell me more about separate thread.

Comment: @AravindRock ok. I've just read your question again, and now I understood something. Can you please rename all your variables to start with a lower case letter? Beacuse it seems like there is a class named Text in Java and there might be a conflict